# Woo Commerce Conditional Tax Depending on products in cart

Tags: woocommerce, conditional-statements, checkout, tax

Hi community I have a pickle of a problem involving TAX, and I really need your help with it. I need a solution whereby if a certain product is added to the cart then the Tax rate for all products that are in the cart drop to the lower tax rate. Here is how this problem arises, one of the products is a service, this product can only be chosen if other products are also in the cart. If the customer chooses this product then the tax rate for all products drops to a lower tax rate, (as the products become part of a service which is taxed here at a lower rate) if the customer doesn't choose this product then the rate remains at the higher rate. - The logic is .. If cart contains product A then tax rate of all products changes to Lower Tax Rate.

I found this code which has a similar logic to it, but not quite there, this changes the tax class based on the subtotal being less than 110. I need to change the tax class based on wether a specific product is in the cart.. I have tried changing "subtotal" to "product" changing the "<= 110" to "= 'fitting' (fitting is the product title) but it didn't work. Any code gurus got any input on this one?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'big_apple_get_tax_class', 1, 2 );
function big_apple_get_tax_class( $tax_class, $product ) {
if ( WC()->cart->subtotal <= 110 )
$tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
return $tax_class;
}
```